# MYSQL Nearest row before with another column having a specific value

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to LEFT JOIN a table to itself depending on the TIMESTAMP (nearest before this row) and another column STABILISATION (with value 1)

query for the test table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `UID` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `CREATED` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `STABILISATION` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`UID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

TRUNCATE `test`;
INSERT INTO `test` (`UID`, `CREATED`, `STABILISATION`) VALUES
('1',   '2014-03-12 09:22:41',  1),
('2',   '2014-03-12 09:24:20',  0),
('3',   '2014-03-12 09:24:35',  0),
('4',   '2014-03-12 09:24:39',  1),
('5',   '2014-03-12 09:24:41',  0),
('6',   '2014-03-12 10:02:17',  1),
('7',   '2014-03-12 10:02:24',  0),
('8',   '2014-03-12 11:00:15',  0),
('9',   '2014-03-12 11:01:08',  1),
('10',  '2014-03-12 11:01:17',  0);
```

I'm trying to get t2_UID COLUMN just like this

```
ID       CREATED                STABILISATION     t2_UID
'1',    '2014-03-12 09:22:41',  1,                1
'2',    '2014-03-12 09:24:20',  0,                1
'3',    '2014-03-12 09:24:35',  0,                1
'4',    '2014-03-12 09:24:39',  1,                4
'5',    '2014-03-12 09:24:41',  0,                4
'6',    '2014-03-12 10:02:17',  1,                6
'7',    '2014-03-12 10:02:24',  0,                6
'8',    '2014-03-12 11:00:15',  0,                6
'9',    '2014-03-12 11:01:08',  1,                9
'10',   '2014-03-12 11:01:17',  0,                9
```

whenever the STABILISATION changes the t2_UID should change also!

The closest I get is with this query:

```
SELECT 
t1.*,
t2.UID AS t2_UID
FROM test AS t1
LEFT JOIN test as t2
ON t2.UID = (SELECT UID
FROM test as t3
WHERE t3.STABILISATION = 1
ORDER BY ABS(TIMEDIFF(t1.CREATED, t3.CREATED))
LIMIT 1)
```

the closest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty way of doing it:

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT t2.UID 
    FROM test t2 
    WHERE STABILISATION=1 AND t2.CREATED <= t.CREATED 
    ORDER BY t2.CREATED DESC LIMIT 1) AS t2_id
FROM test t
ORDER BY t.CREATED;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/140b9/5)

Answer (score 0):

Well done for providing data... the quick and clean way

```
 SELECT a.uid
      , a.created
      , a.stabilisation
      , b.uid
   FROM 
      ( SELECT x.*
             , MAX(y.created) max_created
          FROM test x 
          JOIN test y
            ON y.created <= x.created 
           AND y.stabilisation = 1
         GROUP 
            BY created
      ) a
   JOIN test b
     ON b.created = a.max_created;
+-----+---------------------+---------------+-----+
| uid | created             | stabilisation | uid |
+-----+---------------------+---------------+-----+
| 1a  | 2014-03-12 09:22:41 |             1 | 1a  |
| 0b  | 2014-03-12 09:24:20 |             0 | 1a  |
| 3c  | 2014-03-12 09:24:35 |             0 | 1a  |
| 0d  | 2014-03-12 09:24:39 |             1 | 0d  |
| 4e  | 2014-03-12 09:24:41 |             0 | 0d  |
| 0f  | 2014-03-12 10:02:17 |             1 | 0f  |
| 5g  | 2014-03-12 10:02:24 |             0 | 0f  |
| 3h  | 2014-03-12 11:00:15 |             0 | 0f  |
| 6i  | 2014-03-12 11:01:08 |             1 | 6i  |
| 7j  | 2014-03-12 11:01:17 |             0 | 6i  |
+-----+---------------------+---------------+-----+
```

...or something like that

Comment: Thank you! 
The query looks really simple, but I don't get how the "GROUP BY x.uid" works.

Comment: Rewrite it without the aggregation and the GROUP BY, as per the edit.

Comment: Your edit code: without any "group" and with 2X "order" makes sql looks almost human :) Thanks.

Comment: I found a problem with this query. The MAX(y.UID) happens to function correct due to current UID values, were they actual UUID() it wouldn't function properly. Look at my answer. Jim's answer works in both cases.

Comment: Yes, the original solution assumed sequential ids - oops.